# Mahout - How do I format my input for Naive Bayes classification

Tags: input, mahout

I want to run Naive Bayes classifier in Mahout for a classification problem.
I have searched everywhere on how to format my input, and how to specify the input to mahout, but have not found any useful information.

The only page which was even remotely useful was
[What are the steps needed to use Mahout Native Bayes Classifier Algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841684/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-use-mahout-native-bayes-classifier-algorithm)

But, even there the the author of the answer seems to have used a custom script called **tt**, for parsing the input.

If someone out there knows how to give inputs to Mahout algorithms, please help..

Answer (score 1):

I found the following website: http://chimpler.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/using-the-mahout-naive-bayes-classifier-to-automatically-classify-twitter-messages/.

Apparently Mahout itself also provides some help in formatting. There is an option you can pass in to the mahout binary called seq2encoded, seq2sparse, seqdirectory, etc. I don't know many details regarding their use. This site has more: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Quick+tour+of+text+analysis+using+the+Mahout+command+line.

I don't think that this will take you all the way but hopefully it'll help.

EDIT1: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Creating+Vectors.

EDIT2: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/apache-mahout-in-datastax-enterprise-building-a-classification-system